# Project reactor debugging in intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to reactive programming and still learning. In traditional or imperative programming, I typically put a break point in Intellij and  debug java code, but I'm not able to do the same with reactive code. Is there any plugin available to debug reactive spring boot api?

Comment: you don't need an additional plugin to debug reactive java code in intellij. Just put a breakpoint of the line of code you want to break on.

Answer (score 10):

IntelliJ has support for Reactor debugging since 2019.3 IIRC. They've been improving their async debugger, take into account when the application uses [`reactor-tools`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#reactor-tools-debug), etc...

See the [reference guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#reactor-tools-debug) for enabling `reactor-tools` "debug agent", then in IntelliJ go to Preferences > Languages&Frameworks > Reactive Streams to enable support.

[image: Reactor/Reactive Streams configuration]

Comment: I've run ReactorDebugAgent.init() just fine, but Breakpoint still doesn't work within a Mono

Comment: For those searching the Reactor Debug Mode in community edition, this is in Ultimate version.